# Graphics card using on dual OS performance query

Tags: gpu

if I use my Nvidia graphics card on Linux and sometimes on Windows for gaming(steam), will it be a problem? I see some performance drop. Please , I want to clear about it. I have dual boot.

Comment: The question is totally unclear. What kind of a problem you are asking about?

Comment: i play csgo on windows and sometimes switch to linux and play csgo there too. my question is switching os can effect on gpu ? because, i see performance drop,during switching os

Comment: The performance drop may be a driver issue.